# java: concurrent collections

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, guava

I'm trying to find one or more concurrent collections to use that I can implement the following behavior (the names are contrived for analogy purposes):

```
/**
 * Acts as a broker for a concurrent hash map that stores its keys in order 
 * of submission. At shipping time, the concurrent map is "sealed" 
 * (picture a truck with its cargo door being closed)
 * and its contents presented as an immutable map, and is replaced 
 * by a new concurrent map ready to accept values.
 *
 * Consumers of this class that submit information to it, are expected to 
 * know that this contains a concurrent collection, and should use the 
 * compareAndSet paradigm, e.g. the following:
 *
 * LoadingDock loadingDock = ...
 * boolean done = false;
 * while (!done)
 * {
 *    V oldValue = loadingDock.get();
 *    V newValue = computeNewValue(oldValue, otherInformation);
 *    if (oldValue == null)
 *       done = loadingDock.putIfAbsent(newValue) == null;
 *    else
 *       done = loadingDock.replace(oldValue, newValue) == oldValue;
 * }
 *    
 *
 * Keys and values must be non-null. Keys are not ordered.
 */
class LoadingDock<K,V>
{
    /**
     * analogous to ConcurrentMap's replace, putIfAbsent, and get methods
     */
    public boolean replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue);
    public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value);
    public V get(K key)

    /* see above */
    public Map<K,V> ship();
}
```

I'm having two issues with this.

One is that neither Java nor Guava contain a ConcurrentLinkedHashMap. This makes me wonder why not -- maybe I'm missing the subtleties of such a beast. It looks like I could just make one myself by decorating a ConcurrentHashMap with a class that adds a key to a list if `putIfAbsent()` is ever called and returns null -- I don't need any of the other methods in ConcurrentHashMap beyond the ones above, so there's no way to add a new key to the map except through a call to `putIfAbsent()`.

The other, more insidious issue, is that I can't seem to think of how to implement `ship()` without blocking synchronization -- when ship() is called, the LoadingDock needs to direct all new calls to the new map, and can't return the old map until it is certain all of the concurrent writes are done. (Otherwise I would just use AtomicReference to hold the concurrent map.)

Is there a way to do this w/o having to synchronize?

Comment: I'm thinking I should just do this with `synchronized` for now, and then try to optimize later if performance is an issue... the problem is that I expect it will be.

Comment: One nice way to handle concurrency without synchronization is to use aaka library http://akka.io/downloads/  you can use aaka library from java code. You can also use scala actor library also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) and provide your own comparator that sorts the entries based on a timestamp.  One imagines there's no ConcurrentLinkedMap because there isn't any particularly good way to implement it that's much better than synchronizing a regular one.

For the ship() method just use a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) that has fair mode turned on.  Threads that want to add to the map, acquire the Read lock (weird semantics I know, but it's how it works, think of it as read mode for the actual reference to the map, which is then used normally) so that as many as want can be adding at the same time.  In the ship method you acquire the Write lock and it will block anyone else from changing the map while you export and create a new one.  Fair-mode makes it so that you "cut off" would be adders as close as possible to when ship() is called and just let the existing ones finish.

Comment: could you expand upon the "backwards" semantics of using ReadWriteLock in this way? I think I understand but I'm not 100% sure. It sounds like that because I'm using a ConcurrentMap, anybody who calls `putIfAbsent()` or `get()` or `replace()` without contention, because ConcurrentMap handles the concurrency; whereas any one call in progress to those methods is mutually exclusive to any one call to `ship()`, and any one call to `ship()` is mutually exclusive to any other call to `ship()` -- so this use is isomorphic to read() operations and write() operations. But I'm not completely certain.

Comment: It is.  Last person I tried to teach this too was really confused why I was telling her to get the 'Read' lock when she wanted to *write* values to the map, so I just mentioned off hand to think of it as the 'Read' lock on the pointer to the map, rather than thinking of it as a 'Read-only lock for the map.'

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. What I did to help clarify was `final private Lock mapUsageLock = this.lock.readLock(); final private Lock mapSwapLock = this.lock.writeLock();` to distinguish usage (which can be shared) from changing the map out for a new one.

Comment: btw how the hell do you write unit tests for this sort of thing?

Comment: Good question!  I resort to manual testing and hammer it with The Grinder (assuming it's a webapp of course.)  In jUnit I guess you can use an executor service and hammer on it to check for exceptions when ship() is called, check for happens-before consistency.  Scenarios that say "If this fails it's definitely broken" are doable.  Saying "If this passes it's definitely ok" is tough in jUnit, especially when you don't know how many cores the machine executing the jUnit may have allocated to it.

Comment: Its easier to explain the technique if you describe the lock as a shared/exclusive lock. It then no longer implies whether the data under the lock is being read or written to. You can then say allows concurrent writes and an exclusive (consistent) read. At that point the term read/write on the lock appear as bad API names rather than having conceptual weight.